# regex for working with subdomain and to remove www

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

The following was working for me (to remove www) but I noticed started to mess up a subdomain as it was not specific enough

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

So I added

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^hotels$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hotels.site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Clearly not right (this second part shoudl not be needed at all) - I then understood that I needed to escape the dots (periods) in the url in the first part but also make it more specific now it needs not match www.hotels.site.com - in this case i still want to remove the www but I want to redirect to the subdomain. So in short I always want to remove the www and keep the subdomain working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$ [NC]
```

So this last line is very specific and should ONLY match www.site.com

So why doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

`^www\.site\.com$` will only ever match exactly `www.site.com`.

`^hotels$` will only ever match exactly `hotels` - perhaps you meant `^hotels` which matches anything beginning with `hotels`.

I find your requirements difficult to understand, but if you just want to remove the `www` you could use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

Comment: I thought the $ was always needed to signal the end of what you want to match. I tried your solution but the www doesn't get stripped though it looks like it should work. Matching "www." then redirecting to the %1 which is anything after the www.

Comment: @landed. Try changing the `RewriteRule` to `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1$0 [R,L]`, or if that doesn't work, try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC] RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`. Unfortunately, I am unable to test at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

##### Requirements:

- Rewrite **[www.hotels.example.com](http://www.hotels.example.com)** to *hotels.example.com*
- Rewrite **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** to *example.com*
- Normally *.example.com would also match "hotels.example.com" so make sure we don't infinitely redirect that one, which should be left alone.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?<SubDomain>(?!.*hotels).*)\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

As long as your rule above does NOT match any of the hotel domains, you can do this one (below) second, and order will not matter.  However, if regex above DOES match any of the *.hotel.example.com domains, then you'd need to do this one FIRST so that the hotel sites get redirected correctly FIRST.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?<SubDomain>.*)\.hotels\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hotels.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

##### Matches

```
www.example.com
calamazoo.example.com
kwitcherbeliakin.example.com
regex.is.the.best.example.com
```

##### Does NOT Match

```
example.com
www.hotels.example.com
hotels.example.com
```

Try it out here, with a few tests
https://regex101.com/r/6eMbyL/1